# How to get maximum amplitude (decibel value) of an audio track/mic recording in Android?

Tags: android, decibel

I read plenty of threads even here on SO but still I do not know how to develop a sound level meter to get the sound level from the mic and display it as a decibel value.

I am using the code from the [SoundMeter class](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/SoundMeter.java?r=2) like many suggested, but what this class does is representing the sound amplitude in a scale between 0 to 12, and it goes to 12(maximum value) very easily, just tapping my fingers on the device.

Any suggestion/tutorial will be very appreciated. I understand the calibration issue with mics and the various devices, I can calibrate the devices the app will be installed on against a proper sound meter tool as I am developing a company private app.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found useful information and examples here:

- [GAST](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib)
- [Professional Android Sensor Programming](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118183487.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tapping your finger on a mic is one of the loudest things you can do to a mic. (Like getting tapped right in your ear.) I would not be surprised if that causes a max decibel score. It will also cause clipping in the sound file.

Test with normal voice from a foot away from the mic. That should be midrange on the db level.